# Kafka-Connect-MongoDB Sink Connector Update Issue on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, upsert

I am using JDBC source and kafka-connect-mongodb sink connector to stream data from JDBC to MongoDB.

So far, I am able to get all inserts and updates as a new document (Yes, updates are inserted as new documents) on MongoDB side with **following configs**;

**repo:** https://github.com/hpgrahsl/kafka-connect-mongodb

**configs:**

```
"mongodb.document.id.strategy":"at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.processor.id.strategy.BsonOidStrategy",
"mongodb.post.processor.chain":"at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.processor.DocumentIdAdder",
"mongodb.delete.on.null.values":false,
"mongodb.writemodel.strategy":"at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneDefaultStrategy"
```

What I would like to achieve now is **to update a document in case a row is updated on Oracle side**.

With **below** configurations, I am able to get only the last insert or update done in Oracle side into MongoDB collection as a single document. I mean what I found in MongoDB is a collection with one document which is the last operation.

```
"mongodb.document.id.strategy":"at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy",
"mongodb.key.projection.list": "name,surname",
"mongodb.key.projection.type":"whitelist",
"mongodb.post.processor.chain":"at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.processor.DocumentIdAdder",
"mongodb.writemodel.strategy":"at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy"
```

Appriciate any help in advance.
Many thanks,
Soner

Comment: I figured out the necessary configurations. I created a column on table called _id. It is simply a copy of primary key "id". I used ProvidedInValueStrategy and viola!

Comment: See here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245208/can-we-update-upsert-a-record-in-mongodb-data-source-is-kafka/60705264#60705264