# Can we update/Upsert a record in mongodb? data source is kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

We can update/upsert the record in mongodb BUT is there is any method or function from which we can update or upsert the document directly in mongodb and the source system is kafka and destination is mongodb.

Comment: Sorry not following. Update the document directly as in after reading from kafka process as update/upsert ? Can you expand that please and may be add some code ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes we can update/upsert  the data.
For update you have to define a parameter in Kafka connector.
and whitelist the column on which bases you want to update the record. The property is as followed:

```
document.id.strategy=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy
value.projection.list=tokenNumber
value.projection.type=whitelist
writemodel.strategy=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.UpdateOneTimestampsStrategy
```

Comment: It works! Too bad the documentation is so hard to understand (not enough examples or just takes too much time to understand properly)... the names of the properties are just confusing in my opinion and counter intuitive I see a lot of developers have hard time setting this up.

Comment: Yes bro, you are right the documentation is too hard to understand in one go.

Comment: @nixxo_raa what's the *parameter* and *column* here in your shown configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling through it finally I got the answer. I used following  Mongodb sink [connector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/hpgrahsl/kafka-connect-mongodb)

And after bugging my head on their document for sometime ,I finally figured out the solution .

This is the exact mongodb sink connector configuration I am using

```
{
  "name": "mongodbsync",
  "connector.class": "at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkConnector",
  "topics": "alpha-foobar",
  "mongodb.connection.uri": "mongodb://localhost:27017/kafkaconnect?w=1&journal=true",
  "mongodb.document.id.strategy": "at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.processor.id.strategy.ProvidedInValueStrategy"

}
```

I left `mongodb.writemodel.strategy` blank in my configuration so it is taking the default one

I used the use case 2 of following docs from [github](https://github.com/hpgrahsl/kafka-connect-mongodb) of the same connector

I was dealing with this scenario ,transferring mysql table data with `kafka-jdbc-source connect` to `mongodb sink`.

Also the above strategies can be found in the [official docs](http://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/master/kafka-sink-postprocessors/) as well
Please free to ask any doubts if you have .Thanks

Comment: this method you have suggested doesn't work completely I'm getting an error called  org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Could not convert key `456` into a BsonDocument.\n\tat com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.converter.LazyBsonDocument.getUnwrapped(LazyBsonDocument.java:157)\n\tat com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.converter.LazyBsonDocument.clone(LazyBsonDocument.java:146)\n\tat com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.converter.SinkDocument.clone(SinkDocument.java:45)\n\tat

Comment: you have to make sure that you have serializers active in kafka

Comment: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Could not convert key `456` into a BsonDocument.\n\tat com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.converter.LazyBsonDocument.getUnwrapped(LazyBsonDocument.java:157)\n\tat com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.converter.LazyBsonDocument.clone(LazyBsonDocument.java:146)\n\tat com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.converter.SinkDocument.clone(SinkDocument.java:45)\n\tat  this is the error im getting @Shubh

Comment: let me share my connector so you can understand better

Comment: "config":{
"connector.class" : "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
"tasks.max":"1",
"connection.uri":"mongodb://xx.xx.xx:27017",

"database":"topic1",
"collection":"tag",
"topics":"tag_update_new1",

"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",

"value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8081",

Comment: "document.id.strategy":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy",
"document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.type":"client_id",
"document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.type":"AllowList",
"writemodel.strategy":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy"
} this is my full connector config have i missed out smthn??????